# How do you get field groups to render for a block_content entity loaded programmatically?

Tags: 8

I added some field groups to my display, but they don't render on my custom block_content entity.

```
$blocks = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('block_content')->loadByProperties(['type' => 'footer_bottom']);
if (!empty($blocks)) {
  $block = array_shift($blocks);
  $render_controller = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content');
  $footer_bottom = $render_controller->view($block);

  return $footer_bottom; // won't render field groups.

}
```

I see the field groups in the render array when I dump the $footer_bottom array:

```
  "#fieldgroups" => array:2 [▼
    "group_tricolumn" => {#5505 ▶}
    "group_subfooter" => {#5465 ▶}
  ]
```

Is there another step to process the field groups?

Comment: Why are you loading the block_ content entity instead of the block entity?

Comment: Aren't block_content entities and block entities different?  I thought block entities are for plugins, not for block entities that are fieldable.

Comment: `block` is the configuration entity that the block module uses to render blocks on the page. The `block` entity uses the block_type plugin. One instance the the above plugin uses the content entity `block_content` to create new blocks.

Comment: Can you give an example of loading a block_content instance as a block entity?

Comment: Loading and displaying a block entity instead of a block_content entity: `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block')->load('baz'));`

Comment: Note: you should always try to avoid deprecated methods and classes such as EntityManager.

Comment: This make no sense to me, this looks like the way to load a block plugin, not an instance of a block_content entity.  if I have a block_content entity at /block/728 how do I find the id to pass into the load function above?  It's numeric, not a string like "baz".  It looks to me like you're loading a block plugin, not a block_content entity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41177/discussion-between-eyal-and-oknate).

Answer (score 1):

The field_group module does not currently support the block entities, see [Does not work with blocks [2689501]](https://www.drupal.org/node/2689501)

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out.  That's my issue.  I came up with a way to do it below with "field_group_fields_nest", but it's awkward.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around in the field_group module, I came up with a solution that is rather klunky.  I'm sharing it, but I hope one of you can still give me a better solution.

```
$render_controller = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content');
$footer_bottom = $render_controller->view($block);
field_group_fields_nest($footer_bottom);

$build['footer_bottom']['group_tricolumn'] = $footer_bottom['group_tricolumn'];
$build['footer_bottom']['group_subfooter'] = $footer_bottom['group_subfooter'];
```

I can't just output the entity once I do this, I have to grab the field groups themselves.  So it adds an extra step.  I'd like to know how to render a block_content entity without having to manually create an array from the elements as I'm doing here.